# Why does Xcode 4 not add / create / modify any build directory when I do a build?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I recently upgraded to Xcode4 and noticed that my build/Release-iphoneos folder no longer gets populated with a .app or .dSYM file after I do a build.

**note - any build that is (build for running/testing/profiling). Also why is the build for archiving option gray'd out? in Xcode3 I was able to archive and build my .ipa w/ organizer

Am I doing something wrong or does the new IDE put a release build some place else?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default it's placed in a new folder called 'Derived Data' within your Library folder. If you open up the preferences and go to the 'Locations' tab, you can change it back to the old location if you wish.

Answer (score 2):

That is because Xcode 4 no longer uses that directory. If you look in preferences, you can both see where and change where Xcode 4 builds stuff.